# Purpose of Facade in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel 4.2 and i got stuck in the "facade". I have read the documentation in the official site of Laravel and taken many references from the other sites too. Now I know how to create simple facade.

But My question is what is the main purpose of the facade? I realised facade can be used to call a class's method statically. Is their any other application of facade in Laravel beside this?

Answer (score 2):

First, keep in mind that Facades in Laravel isn't specifically just a Laravel feature.

Facades is a general design pattern used in software to reduce the complexity of interacting with a complex system, or library, by providing a simpler interface.

In Laravel the facades were created with that exact purpose; to help new developers understand and interact with a relatively complex system through a simple interface.

Additionally, it is much easier to test a static facade interface than it is to test a complex system.